# Microsoft Exchange 2016 - ApplicationImpersonation

Tags: exchange, microsoft

I want an application (e.g. application123) to write a mail on behalf of all users. For this purpose a user is configured within the application (e.g. myImpersoUser).

I want to realize this via ApplicationImpersonation, unfortunately it does not work yet.
If I assign the "send_As" permission manually, it works (so SMTP and authentication on the part of the application seems to be ok).

Current setting:

- AD Security Group (universal) -> App_Mailsender (is a mail-enabled AD group, the same game already tested with a distribution list).

-Management Scope created, which refers to the AD group

```
New-ManagementScope -Name "S_Mailsend" -RecipientRestrictionFilter {MemberOfGroup -eq "CN=App_Mailsender,OU=X,OU=Y,DC=domainName,DC=local"}
```

-then RoleAsignment performed

```
New-ManagementRoleAssignment -Name: "R_Mailsend" -Role:ApplicationImpersonation -CustomRecipientWriteScope: "S_Mailsend" -User: "myImpersoUser@domain.com"
```

Unfortunately I get the message **"550 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender"**.

Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have configured your application in order to identify the account to impersonate after configuring impersonation for the specific user: **[Identify the account to impersonate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-identify-the-account-to-impersonate)**

Besides, I tried to create a dynamic distribution group, and use the property **`MemberOfGroup`** to add members of another dynamic distribution group or distribution group in the recipient filter , so that confirm if the property **`MemberOfGroup`** is valid in the recipient filter:
[image]

[image]

However, when I tried to get a list of the dynamic distribution group "DDG02", the output didn't show any results:

[image]

Based on the test result, it seems that the **MemberOfGroup** is not valid in the recipient filter.

If your application has identified the account to impersonate, I think you could add a custom attribute to all members which locate in the group, and use the custom attributes to add these members in the recipient filter of your custom management scope, then create a management scope to include these members and run the **`New-ManagementRoleAssignment`** cmdlet to add the permission to impersonate the members of the specified scope:

[image]

After that, try using the application to write a mail on behalf of all users and see if there is any difference.

Comment: thanks for your post. Why doesn't the "MemberOfGroup" function work if Microsoft intended it to? Or in which constellations does it work? I don't want to go the way you described, because otherwise I would have to build another script, which regularly checks if new mailboxes exist and have / don't have the attribute. I would prefer a central place (AD group etc.), which regulates the function.

Comment: Hi, based on my knowledge and research, the parameters "-RecipientRestrictionFilter"(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-managementscope?view=exchange-ps) and "-RecipientFilter"(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-dynamicdistributiongroup?view=exchange-ps) use the same OPath filter syntax and filterable properties, I just to use another command to preview the members in group and see if I could get the group members.

Comment: Hello, thank you.

But how can I realize this in my way? Without having to resort to the AD attributes (as you described).

Comment: Hi, @user612985, please use the same account that you used to post the question, it's misleading to see two accounts from the same person to interact in the same question. If you need help for your account let me know.